# How to compute the ranks of an array in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

How to get the ranking of an array, like pandas.DataFrame.rank()?

For exmaple, for this array:

```
a = tf.constant([0, 2, 3, 3])
```

The result i would expect is:

```
([0, 1, 2, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I find:

```
__, rank = tf.unique(a)
print(rank)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int32)>
```

Comment: These are not ranks but indices of the unique values in the array, see [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unique).